# Describe "corruption" in higher academia (research for a novel)

Tags: publications, research-process, humanities

if you were to imagine a dystopian future in which academia was corrupted to a point in which it was no longer fit to fulfill its purpose…could you describe what that would look like? What would be the symptoms at the systemic/personnel level? Could you prescribe a treatment process?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia SE. Your question is definitely off-topic here, because it's mainly speculation. Maybe you can check if it's ok on [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) or [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). Personally, I'd suggest you to look at current cases of corruption which can be easily found in the news around the world.